# Using Visual Studio 2008 with C/C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008

I've decided to dive into some code written in C, and I'd like to use Visual Studio. I have Visual Studio 2008 Professional which I'm using now primarily for C#, but I've noticed that there are no options for C in Visual Studio.

Also I've noticed that although Visual Studio has projects, and whatnot for C++ that the build options are all greyed out so I cannot build C++. What do I need to build C++? Can I add projects and building for C in Visual Studio?

Comment: A C++ compiler can compile 99.9% of valid C code. You may be out of luck if you want certain C99 features like variable-length arrays, or if your code uses variables called `new`, but otherwise you should be pretty safe.

Comment: Yes the common subset of C and C++ is nearly the complete C90 language (if you have C99, that's less true).  But about no idiomatic C code will not compile on a C++ compiler.  Most common culprit: not casting the result of malloc() (and C programmers insist that this is proper style).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio doesn't distinguish much between C++ and C. Instead, you create a C++ project, and then simply add .c files to it. It will by default compile .c files as C code, and .cpp files as C++.

Comment: However like I said in my post VS will not let me compile C++ either.

Answer (score 1):

When you install Visual Studio, it offers the different languages as options - perhaps you chose not to install C++?

If that's the case, you'll need to run the installer again.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you've installed the C++ compiler + related options?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have Visual C++ installed, I believe it can compile C as well. You'll just have a C++ project that doesn't use C++ features. ;D

Answer (score 0):

This has already been discussed about the C/C++ compiler [in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210988/for-c-developers-is-it-worth-to-switch-from-vs2005-to-vs2008/1210995#1210995). I wouldn't even bother using Visual Studio 2008 if you're already using 2005 (or for that matter some other compiler/ide) for your C/C++ projects. There's just pretty much no benefits to upgrading your environment from 2005.

Comment: Not entirely true, one big benefit of upgrading to vs2008 is that it actually works relatively well in Vista, something that cannot be said of 2005.

Comment: I developed in 2005 on Vista for quite some time, and that was before Service Pack 1. Worked very well, as long as you download all the required updates, which are available via Windows Update.

Comment: If nothing else, VS2008 was noticeably snappier than VS2005 for me.

Answer (score 0):

To start a new empty C or C++ project in VC++:

> File > New > Project... > Visual C++ >
>   Win32 Project > OK > [Application
>   Settings] > [Empty project] > OK

Then add new source file to the project by right clicking on your project name:

> Add > New Item... > Visual C++ > Code > C++ File (.cpp) > Add

Just make sure you explicitly give your file a .c extension if you want.

To tell VC++ to compile your whole project as C and not C++, right click on your project name:

> Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Advanced > Compile As > Compile as C Code (/TC) > OK

(That should already be the case for individual file with a .c extension.) You might also check the various other settings is suitable while you're there.

Like RichieHindle said, you might not have installed VC++ during the installation of VS. In that case, you would need to install it before you can do anything obviously. Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Depending on what the C/C++  code does, you might want to create a Console App in stage #1 above.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't decide whether I wanted to write "Win32 Project" or "Win32 Console Application" above, but since one can actually change it in "Application Settings", it doesn't really matter.